# How to call php function inside ajax method

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

Here I have the following code. I would like to call a function in a file named functions.php and pass in $var1 as the parameter, how would I go about doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#your_teams234").change(function() {

                var team = $("#your_teams234").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'functions.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: 'members=' + team
                }).done(function(requests) {
                    console.log(requests);
                    requests = JSON.parse(requests);
                    $('#teammates').empty();
                    requests.forEach(function(request) {
                        $('#teammates').append('<p class="myDivs">' + request.fname + ' ' + request.lname + '</p>')
                    })
                    $('.myDivs').click(function()
                    { 
                        $var1 = $(this).text();
                        alert($var1);
                    });
                })
            })
        })
```

Comment: Post to a brand new script file where you `include()` the `functions.php` file and call it from there.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Im sorry could you maybe show an example I am a little slow learning this

Comment: It's not really possible to give you an example, because an example would just be a script to process your ajax request. Just create a new file, e.g `fetch_teammates.php`. Change your ajax request to use this new file. In that file, you need to use [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to include your `functions.php` file. After the require, you can call the function in `functions.php` from `fetch_teammates.php`.

Comment: If you are just performing a "search", then it is more common to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.  `$_POST` is more commonly used when you are writing to the server (INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE).

Comment: Typically (and it holds true to this question) when a question is tagged with three separate programming languages/layers, the question has been insufficiently narrowed and is actually asking multiple questions / asking for multiple techniques.  You are asking for help, but we see no attempt to write PHP or SQL.  "How to do an AJAX search" is an amazingly over-populated topic on Stack Overflow as well as the web in general.  Please research more before asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will have files that contain functions/definitions and others that handle requests. (This is not necessary, just common practice)

Files that handle requests will include any relevant functions/definitions from those other files

For this case, let's use `functions.php` to contain your main functions and `actions.php` as a page to handle requests

See the below setup

```php
// functions.php file
function get_team_members(string $team_name){
    // return a list of members based on $team_name
}
```

```php
// actions.php file
include "functions.php";

$action = $_POST["action"] ?? "";
$data = null;
switch($action){
    case "get_team_members":
        $data = get_team_members($_POST["team"] ?? "");
        break;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

```js
// js file
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your_teams234").change(function() {

        var team = $("#your_teams234").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'actions.php', // update the url to request from actions.php
            method: 'post',
            data: { // update data to reflect expected data
                action: "get_team_members",
                team: team,
            },
        })
        .done(function(requests) { ... })
    })
})
```

Comment: Instead of `$data = null;`, I might add a `default: $data = null`.  In more modern PHP, `match()` is available.

Comment: @mickmackusa sure, you can do as you like. The code presented here is not something I would ever use in any of my work but more as an easy way to understand what's happening using the language basics

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are trying to declare a variable as in PHP in jQuery.

```
$var1 = $(this).text();
```

Try below and hope your issue will be resolved.

1. Your PHP Function should looks like this in `functions.php`
   Assuming you are retrieving data from a database,

```
public function ajaxGetData()
{
   //If you need any identifier from the front end
   $user_id = $this->request->getPost('user_id');
   //Access the database to get data (using codeigniter here)
   $my_model = new Model_Name();
   $data = $my_model->findAll();
   if (!$data)
      echo "FALSE";
   else
      echo json_encode($data);
}
```

2. And make sure you are calling the function name in your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "functions/ajaxGetData",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        user_id: id //pass the id here if required (optional)
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data != "FALSE"){
            var jArr = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#teammates').empty();
            jArr.forEach(element => {
                    $('#teammates').append('<p class="myDivs">' + element.fname + ' ' + element.lname + '</p>')
                })
            }
        }
        else $("#teammates").html('<p>No data found</p>');
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    },
});
```

3. To add the on click function, add separate jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 
    $(document).on("click", ".myDivs", function(){
        var text = $(this).html();
        alert(text);
    });
    
});
```